# At $2:00$pm car's speedometer reads $30$mph, and at $2:10$pm it reads $35$mph. Use the Mean Value Theorem to find acceleration the car must achieve.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

I'm only assuming that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are assigned to each respective velocity, but I'm not sure how the mean value theorem can be applied to distance rate and time.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem states that for a differentiable function $f$, there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that the following equality holds:
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
Our function $f(x)$ is the velocity as a function of time. I.e. for some time $x$, $f(x)$ outputs a velocity.

For the sake of convenience, let's reduce the units of the question, and the times to fractions of hours. Note that 10 minutes is $10/60 = 1/6$ of an hour:
$$f(0/6) = 30, f(1/6) = 35$$
Then we get that 
$$f'(c) = \frac{35-30}{1/6-0/6} = \frac{5}{1/6} = \frac 5 1 \cdot \frac 6 1 = 30$$
We note that since $f(x)$ denotes the speed of the vehicle at some point in time $x$, the derivative $f'(x)$ denotes the velocity of the vehicle. This makes sense because the derivative is a rate of change, and acceleration is the rate of change of velocity.

So $f'(c)$ is the acceleration at some point $c$. This acceleration is $30$. We note that we measured time in hours and miles per hour, so we can just put the units back in: the rate of change is $30$ miles per hour per hour, i.e. the acceleration is $30\mathrm{mph}^2$.

(To be absolutely clear: $\mathrm{mph}^2$ is just the unit for acceleration.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the acceleration at time $t$ is given by $v'(t)$ where $v(t)$ is the speed. The mean value theorem now states that for all $a,b$ there exists a $t_0\in(a,b)$ such that
$$
a(t_0)= v'(t_0) = \frac{v(b)-v(a)}{b-a}.
$$

Comment: Are v(b) and v(a) functions though, or is it simply 35-30? I don't understand.

Comment: The speed $v$ is a functon of the time and $v(a)$ and $v(b)$ are values. We pick $a=2$ and $b = 2 + \frac{10}{60} = 2\frac{1}{6}$. Then the speed at these times are $v(a) = 30$ and $v(b) = 35$.

Answer (score 0):

Mean Value Theorem states that for f(x) on [a,b], given f(x) is continuous and differentiable on [a,b], that f'(x) must, at a point, equal $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

Applying to this, knowing that the derivative of velocity is acceleration, where f(x) is velocity and x is in hours, $\frac{f(2+\frac{1}{6})-f(2)}{\frac{1}{6}}$ = $\frac{5}{\frac{1}{6}}$ = $30$

Because the numerator is a velocity $\frac{mi}{h}$ and the denominator is a time unit $h$, the answer should be in miles/hour/hour.

Therefore, by the Mean Value Theorem, there is a time between 2:00 PM and 2:10 PM when the car's acceleration is 30 mi/h^2.